# React navigation conditionally render the screen

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-navigation

im using react native stack navigation.when user login and verify succesfully i want to move to dashboard screen .when next time user opens the app dashboard screen needs to render instead of login

i tried this:(im getting error The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"DashBoard"} was not handled by any navigator.
Do you have a screen named 'DashBoard'?)

```
const StackNavigator = () => {
  const user = useContext(UserContext);
 
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      {user ? (
        <>
         <Stack.Group>
            <Stack.Screen name="DashBoard" component={DashBoard} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Modal" component={Modal} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Quiz" component={Quiz} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Summary" component={Summary} />

      <Stack.Screen name="Loading" component={Loading} />

      <Stack.Screen name="Notes" component={Notes} />
      <Stack.Screen name="EditProfile" component={EditProfile} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />

      <Stack.Screen name="Chatbot" component={Chatbot} />

      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        </Stack.Group>
        </>
       
      ):(
        <Stack.Group>
 <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="VerifyOTP" component={VerifyOTP} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Landing" component={LandingPage} />
        </Stack.Group>
      )}
      
       
     
     
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default StackNavigator;
```